# How to specify SYBASE Database name in ODBC in .NET

Tags: .net, odbc, sybase

I'm using Sybase ODBC driver in C#.
Works well but I cannot find the way to specify database I'm operating.

As workaround I'm using this double dots notification

```
 SELECT * FROM DB_NAME..TABLE_NAME
```

But I wonder if there is a way to specify DB in connection string (As in MS SQL - Initial Catalog)

Below is code I'm using to create connection string:

```
string connString = string.Format ( "Driver={{{0}}};srvr={1};uid={2};pwd={3};Initial Catalog={4};",
 GetConfigEntry ( "SYBASE_DRIVER" ),
 GetConfigEntry ( "SERVER" ), 
 GetConfigEntry ( "LOGIN" ),
 GetConfigEntry ( "PSWD" ),
 GetConfigEntry ( "DB" )
);
```

**EDIT:**
I'm using {MERANT 3.60 32-BIT Sybase} driver

Comment: You can also use as the first command USE <DB_NAME>

Comment: I;ve tried that: USE DB; SELECT ... and says unknown command near ;

Answer (score 1):

Using the following connection string you can use Sybase from C# and specify the initial catalog.

```
Data Source=\\myserver\myvolume\mypat;Initial Catalog=mydd.add;User    ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;ServerType=REMOTE;
```

Anyway your connection string has the initial catalog property too.

Comment: Initial catalog doesnt work to me... Maybe it is important I'm using {MERANT 3.60 32-BIT Sybase} driver

Comment: Mmm ... try this: Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;User 
ID=userName;Extended Properties="DRIVER={MERANT 3.60 32-BIT 
Sybase};UID=userName;DB=testDB;SRVR=DSRV0002;PWD=password";Initial 
Catalog=testDB

Answer (score 0):

1. You may be misunderstanding some fundamental here.  Unlike native connections to Sybase or MS, an ODBC connection deals with one and only one db_name as identified in the Datasource definition.  ODBC does not understand, or have the capacity to change, db contexts. Therefore, create a new Datasource definition for each db_name you need to connect to.

   - Note that each ODBC driver (vendor) has its own peculiarities
   - Using the native connection (CT-Library) is much, much faster than ODBC, and does not have limitations such as these.
     .
2. Sybase also allows a default `db_name` to be set per login.  You can change that, so that any connection from that login goes directly to a specific db.
3. Sybase certainly allows switching db contexts, **after** you are connected.  You can:`USE db_name
   GO`
   Do not forget the `"GO"`.  "`USE db_name`" has to be the only command in the batch.
4. If you are not the DBA, and they have put you (as developer) in a db_name, for containment purposes, and you cannot change that, then using the fully qualified table name "`db_name.user.table_name`" is the correct method.  Each component has a default (`db_name` is the current db; `user` is `dbo`).  It is not a workaround, it is the required method, as per the ISO/IEC/ANSI SQL Standard.